# How to make visible a leftBarButtonItem created programmatically and set backgroundimage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

Below code is working fine in my application. But that leftbarbuttonitem is invisible. And I can't set background image to `leftBarButtonItem`. I did some thing wrong, but I don't know what is the mistake? Is it possible to make visible and set background image?

```
UIImageView *NavigationBarImage =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
NavigationBarImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"mapbutton.png"];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:NavigationBarImage];
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;

UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(goBack)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;

-(void)goBack
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to add a backgroundImage to your navigation item you have to add a custom button, like bellow:

```
UIButton *tempButton                            =       [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
tempButton.frame                                =       CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 30);
tempButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted            =       YES;
tempButton.backgroundColor                      =       [UIColor clearColor];
[tempButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[tempButton setTitle:@"Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[tempButton addTarget:self action:@selector(goBack) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *backBtn                        =         [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:tempButton];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem           =       backBtn;
```

And to add a background Image to navigation bar you can use the following code

```
 [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"header.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.. but now also that leftbarbuttonitem is invisible only

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
UIButton *tempButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
tempButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
tempButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
tempButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

Comment: [tempButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"food.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[tempButton addTarget:self action:@selector(goBack) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *backBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:tempButton];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBtn;
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mapsnav.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];}

Comment: Your viewdidload looks fine, is your navigation bar is visible, or you can emil me your project then may be then i'll be able to debug it. If you want email me at imneev@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *home = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];  
UIImage *homeImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"YOUR_IMAGE.png"];  
[home setBackgroundImage:homeImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
[home addTarget:self action:@selector(your_Action)  
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];  
home.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 69, 26);  
UIBarButtonItem *button2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:home];
[[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:button2];
[button2 release];
button2 = nil;
```